# how to filter fields from jsonb type column while querying on postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Here is my table (simplified, only significant columns):

```
CREATE TABLE details(
  id serial primary key,
  name text,
  Address jsonb  );
```

And some sample Data

```
# Select * from details

 id |   name   | Address 
----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------
  1 | Batman   |  {"city":"Gotham City","street":"1007 Mountain Drive"}      
  2 | Superman |  {"city":"Metropolis","street":"344 Clinton Street"}         
  3 | Flash    |  {"city":"Central City","street":"122 Englewood street"}
```

Now I would like to select only name and City field of Address, Query would be

```
Select name, Address -> 'city' as Address from details

   name   | Address 
----------+------------------
 Batman   |  "Gotham City"      
 Superman |  "Metropolis"
 Flash    |  "Central City"
```

But I want it to be filtered as shown below.

```
   name   | Address 
----------+-------------------------
 Batman   |  {"city":"Gotham City"}      
 Superman |  {"city":"Metropolis"}         
 Flash    |  {"city":"Central City"}
```

Is it possible to select only some fields from jsonb type column? If it is possible then what would be the query ?

Comment: you can specify key yourself: `Select name, concat('{"city":"',Address ->> 'city','"}')::json as Address from details`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include only 1 field, your query can be fairly easy:

```
select name, jsonb_build_object('city', address -> 'city') address
from   details
```

However, if you want to include multiple fields, things will get complex. You could f.ex. remove unwanted keys one-by-one with the `-` operator, like: `jsonb_column - 'key1' - 'key2'`:

```
select name, address - 'street' address
from   details
```

But this will only work, when you have a fairly few fields inside of the JSON column (and they are well defined).

If you want a general solution, you should use some aggregation:

```
select name, (select jsonb_object_agg(e.key, e.value)
              from   jsonb_each(address) e
              where  e.key in ('city')) address
from   details
```